# Why OpenSea marketplace API return 'null' for signature?

Tags: opensea, seaport

I'm trying to fulfill an existing listing on OpenSea marketplace programmatically using seaport-js (SDK of seaport protocol). I used OpenSea's [get_order](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/get_order) to fetch an order but the signature is `null`. Based on the API doc, this is the offer makers / seller's signature, not the taker/buyer's, so I'm expecting the API to return it. Any idea what this signature is and where to fetch it?

Code that fetches the order:

```
async function fetchOrderFromOpenSea(
  liquidityZone: string,
  orderHash: string,
) {
  const options: RequestInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': OPENSEA_API_KEY,
    },
  }
  const url = `https://api.opensea.io/api/v2/orders/chain/${liquidityZone}/protocol/${SEAPORT_PROTOCOL_ADDRESS}/${orderHash}`
  const response = await fetch(url, options)
  const { order } = await response.json()
  return order
}
```